# In Objective-C, if I have a call to a block in a method that returns a value, how to return the value after the block has executed?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Please consider this sample code:

```
- (long)someMethod {

   long returnValue;

   [MFPDFConverter createPDFFromEmail:emailToConvert completionHandler:^(long longObtainedFromBlock) {
        NSLog(@"Here we are");
        returnValue = longObtainedFromBlock;        
   }];

   return returnValue;

}
```

How can I refactor the method to wait for the block to end before returning the value ? Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

maybe put the return value in block

```
- (void)someMethod:(void(^)(long returnValue))callback {
   [MFPDFConverter createPDFFromEmail:emailToConvert completionHandler:^(long longObtainedFromBlock) {
        NSLog(@"Here we are");
       if (callback) {
           callback(longObtainedFromBlock);
       }
   }];
}
```